# Rectangle turn 90 degrees libgdx

Tags: java, graphics, libgdx

If I have a tiled map, where all tiles are `50x50px` and I want to make a sliding effect where a tile block turns 90 degrees so his route looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zt8p.png

How can I mathematically implement this so the rectangle perfectly turns and lands on the perfect coordinates which are in this case x-50, y + 50 because it is going to the left and to the top.

I could not find anything similar to this.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a rotate function based off of whatever you're trying to rotate, whether it's a box2d object, or an image, and translate the object up as it rotates to accommodate for the rotation